# Numbers with decimal expansions of only 4 and 7 is $E = \cap_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n $

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Fix that $E$ is the set of real numbers $x \in [0,1]$ whose decimal expansion contains only the digits $4$ and $7$. Let $S_n$ be the set consisting of all natural numbers not exceeding $10^n$ whose digits consists only of $4$ or $7$. For example,
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        S_1 &= \{4, 7\} \\
        S_2 &= \{44, 77, 47, 74\} \\
        S_3 &= \{444, 744, 474, 447, 774, 747, 477, 777\} \\
        \vdots
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}

I want to prove that

> $E$ can be defined as:
> \begin{equation*}
>     E = \cap_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n, \textrm{ where } E_n = \cup_{a \in S_n} \left[\frac{a}{10^n}, \frac{a+1}{10^{n}}\right]  
> \end{equation*}

For instance,
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        E_1 &= [0.4, 0.5] \cup [0.7, 0.8] \\
        E_2 &= [0.44, 0.45] \cup [0.77, 0.78] \cup [0.47, 0.48] \cup [0.74, 0.75] \\
        &\vdots
    \end{split}
    \end{equation*}

The $E \subseteq \cap_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n$ part is immediate but I am having trouble proving $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n \subseteq E$ rigorously (I know this is immediate as well but I have to prove that rigorously). Here's my naive attempt so far:

Ley $y \in \cap_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n$. Then, $y \in E_n$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, that is,
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        y \in E_1 &= [0.4, 0.5] \cup [0.7, 0.8] \\
        y \in E_2 &= [0.44, 0.45] \cup [0.77, 0.78] \cup [0.47, 0.48] \cup [0.74, 0.75] \\
        &\vdots
    \end{split}
    \end{equation*}

Since $y \in E_1$, either $y \in [0.4, 0.5]$ or $y \in [0.7, 0.8]$. If $y \in [0.4, 0.5]$, then since $y \in E_2$ as well, we have $y \in [0.44, 0.45]$, or $y \in [0.47, 0.48]$.

Now, the issue is that I can keep typing up this proof indefinitely and never complete it. How can I complete the proof in a finite (and reasonable) amount of time? I thought of using induction but I am not sure what that would look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y\in\bigcap_{n\ge 1}E_n$. For each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ there is a unique $a_n\in S_n$ such that $y\in\left[\frac{a_n}{10^n},\frac{a_n+1}{10^n}\right]$.

- Show that $a_{n+1}\in\{10a_n+4,10a_n+7\}$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$.
- Let $d_1=a_1$, and let $d_{n+1}=a_{n+1}-10a_n\in\{4,7\}$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$.
- Show that $y=0.d_1d_2d_3\ldots\;$.

Comment: Great answer ! Thanks for that piece.

Comment: If I understand the first line of your answer correctly, shouldn't it be: For each $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+, \exists \textrm{ a unique } a_{mn} \in S_n$ s.t. $y \in\left [\frac{a_{mn}}{10^n}, \frac{a_{mn}+1}{10^n}\right]$ and $m = 1, 2, \dots, 2^n$?

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson: No. For $y=0.4747\ldots$, for instance, $a_1=4$, $a_2=47$, $a_3=474$, and so on. Why do you think so?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott If we take $n =1$, then (as in your answer) there is a unique $a_1 \in S_1 = \{4, 7\}$ such that $y \in\left [\frac{a_{n}}{10^n}, \frac{a_{n}+1}{10^n}\right]$. How is $a_n$ unique? Should it be "at least one" instead? (Sorry, I'm having some trouble following your answer currently.)

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson: There is only one: the intervals $\left[\frac{a}{10^n},\frac{a+1}{10^n}\right]$ for $a\in S_n$ are pairwise disjoint, so a real number $y$ can be in at most one of them.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Don't we have at least one of $y \in\left [\frac{4}{10}, \frac{4+1}{10}\right]$ or $y \in\left [\frac{7}{10}, \frac{7+1}{10}\right]$ for the $n=1$ case?

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson: Yes; in the first case $a_1=4$, and in the second case $a_1=7$. In each case the value of $a_1$ is completely unambiguous.

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson: I would, if I could figure out what your misconception is. I’m afraid that to me the statement before the bullet points seems self-evident, especially after this string of comments, and I have no idea how to make it clearer. And if you’re stuck there, nothing that I add to the bullet points is going to help. Try taking a number in $E$, like $0.4774744\ldots$, and actually determining the first few $a_n$; in this case they’re $4,47,477,4774,47747,477474,\ldots$. Then look at, say, $a_n,10a_n+4$, and $10a_n+7$ for small $n$, compute $d_n$ for small $n$, and see what’s going on.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott When I attempted the question, I had $y \in \left[\frac{a}{10^n}, \frac{a+1}{10^{n}}\right]$ for each $n$, but in your answer, you have $y \in \left[\frac{a_n}{10^n}, \frac{a_{n}+1}{10^{n}}\right]$. How exactly are you defining $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$? I think, besides this point, I follow the rest of your answer after doing the exercise you suggested.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Pardon me, that was a typo. I've edited my comment.

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson: I defined $a_n$ at the beginning of the answer. If $y$ is in $E_n$, it is in exactly one of the closed intervals $\left[\frac{a}{10^n},\frac{a+1}{10^n}\right]$ whose union is $E_n$, and $a_n$ is the unique $a\in S_n$ such that $y\in\left[\frac{a}{10^n},\frac{a+1}{10^n}\right]$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I think I finally fully grasped your answer after this last comment. Thank you!

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson: Excellent! You’re welcome.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Can you please provide some hints on how I might be able to prove that $y=0.d_1d_2\ldots$ (your last bullet).

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson: Just use the fact that for each $n\ge 1$, $$y\in\left[\frac{d_1d_2\dots d_n}{10^n},\frac{d_1d_2\dots d_n+1}{10^n}\right]\;,$$ where by $d_1d_2\ldots d_n$ I mean the string of $n$ digits, not the product.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott You might find this of interest: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3748082/proving-that-a-number-with-decimal-expansion-of-only-4-and-7-is-e-cap-n-1 :)