# Completing the proof using strong induction for $E = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty E_n $

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, induction, alternative-proof

I want to follow up my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3745180/numbers-with-decimal-expansions-of-only-4-and-7-is-e-cap-n-1-inftye-n/3745297?noredirect=1#comment7703654_3745297).

My original question was:

> Fix that $E$ is the set of real numbers $x \in [0,1]$ whose decimal expansion contains only the digits $4$ and $7$. Let $S_n$ be the set consisting of all natural numbers not exceeding $10^n$ whose digits consists only of $4$ or $7$. For example,
> \begin{equation*}
>     \begin{split}
>         S_1 &= \{4, 7\} \\
>         S_2 &= \{44, 77, 47, 74\} \\
>         S_3 &= \{444, 744, 474, 447, 774, 747, 477, 777\} \\
>         \vdots
>     \end{split}
> \end{equation*}
>
> I want to prove that
> $E$ can be defined as:
> \begin{equation*}
>     E = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty E_n, \textrm{ where } E_n = \cup_{a \in S_n} \left[\frac{a}{10^n}, \frac{a+1}{10^{n}}\right]  
> \end{equation*}
>
> For instance,
> \begin{equation*}
>     \begin{split}
>         E_1 &= [0.4, 0.5] \cup [0.7, 0.8] \\
>         E_2 &= [0.44, 0.45] \cup [0.77, 0.78] \cup [0.47, 0.48] \cup [0.74, 0.75] \\
> E_3 &= [0.444, 0.445] \cup [0.447, 0.448] \cup [0.474, 0.475] \cup [0.477, 0.478]\\
>         &\cup [0.744, 0.745] \cup [0.747, 0.748] \cup [0.774, 0.775] \cup [0.777, 0.778]  \\
>         &\vdots
>     \end{split}
>     \end{equation*}

and I had no idea how I could prove $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty E_n \subseteq E$. My original question also got a wonderful response, but I eventually came up with an alternative proof. Here is that proof:

> Let $y \in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty E_n$. Then, $y \in E_n$ for each $n$ which implies that $y$ is in exactly one of the closed intervals $\left[\frac{a_n}{10^n}, \frac{a_n+1}{10^{n}}\right]$. Define the decimal expansion of $y$ as $y=0.d_1d_2d_3\ldots\;$. First we show that $d_1$ is either $4$ or $7$. STTC that $d_1 \notin \{4, 7\}$.
>
> 1. If $d_1 \in \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$, then $y\le0.4$. If $y<0.4$, then $y\notin E_1$, which is not possible. If $y=0.4$, then $y\notin E_2$, which is also not possible.
> 2. If $d_1 \in \{5, 6\}$, then $0.5\le y \le 0.7$. If $0.5< y < 0.7$, then $y\notin E_1$, which is not possible. If $y=0.5$ or $y=0.7$, then $y \notin E_2$, which is not possible.
> 3. If $d_1 \in \{8, 9\}$, then $0.8 \le y< 1$. If $0.8 <y< 1$, then $y\notin E_1$, which is not possible. If $y =0.8$, then $y\notin E_2$, which is also not possible.

Thus, $d_1 \in \{4, 7\}$. Similarly, suppose to the contrary that $d_2 \notin \{4, 7\}$. **My idea is that I want to show that if $d_2 \notin \{4, 7\}$, then that would force that either $y \notin E_2$ or $y \notin E_3$, which would signal a definite pattern, which is all I want (no need for a formal induction).** Thus:

> 1. If $d_2 \in \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$, then $0.400 \le y \le 0.740$. If $0.400 \le y < 0.440$, then $y \notin E_2$ which is not possible. If $0.440\le y <0.444$, then $y \notin E_3$. If $0.444 \le y < \dots$,
> 2. If $d_2 \in \{5, 6\}$, then $0.450 \le y \le 0.770$. If $y = 0.45$, then $y \notin E_3$. If $0.45 < y < 0.47 $, then $y \notin E_2$. If $0.47 \le y < 0.474$, then $y \notin E_3$. If $0.474 \le y \dots$,
> 3. If $d_2 \in \{8, 9\}$, then $0.480 \le y \le 0.80$.

I haven't developed bullet 3. for $d_2$ because I couldn't even complete the argument in the first two bullets for $d_2$. **Can someone please suggest how the argument for $d_2$ can be completed? (Again, no need for formal induction. I just want to develop an argument for $d_2$ that is similar to $d_1$.)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inductive step, or maybe your proof as a whole, can perhaps be simplified by one of the following two viewpoints:

***1. A dynamical viewpoint***

Consider the 10-tupling map $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$,

$$f:x \mapsto 10x \mod 1,$$

where one multiplies $x$ by $10$ and removes the integer part (another way of writing it: $f(x) = 10x - \lfloor10x \rfloor$).

*Who cares?*

Why define this function? It makes most sense in digit form:

> if $x = 0.d_1d_2d_3\ldots,\ $ $f(x) = 0.d_2d_3d_4\ldots$

That is, $f$ acts by shifting all the digits up by one, forgetting the first digit.

From this alone, you can very quickly verify the following points, and you only need the first.

1. If $x\in E$, $f(x)\in E$.
2. Moreover, $f: E \to E$ is a 2-to-1 surjection.
3. For any $n\in \mathbb N$, $f(E_{n+1}) = E_n$. ($f(E_1) = [0,1]$.)

**Regarding the second step of your induction**: (EDITED.)

A consequence of property 3.:

$$ y \in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n \implies \ \forall\,n\geq 2,\ y \in E_n \stackrel{\text{3.}}\implies \ \forall\,n\geq 2,\ f(y) \in f(E_n) = E_{n-1} \implies f(y) \in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty E_n. $$

I.e.,

$$ y \in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n \implies f(y) \in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty E_n.\tag{1} $$

Now suppose $y = 0.d_1d_2d_3\ldots \in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty E_n$. The digits of $f(y)$ are given by

$$f(y) = 0.e_1e_2e_3\ldots \qquad\text{where, for every }n,\ e_n = d_{n+1}.$$

By (1), we know $f(y) \in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty E_n$ and so, by your "base case," its first digit is in $\{4,7\}$.

But this first digit, $e_1 = d_2$, is simply the second digit of $y$, so you're done: $d_2 \in \{4,7\}$.

Hopefully you can see how this can be generalised to $d_{n+1}$ (apply $f$ more than once). No inductive assumption required!

***2. Aside: a fractal geometry viewpoint***

$E$ is really just like the (middle-thirds) Cantor set. So any argument that works for the Cantor set should work here as well (the Cantor set can be defined in terms of base 3 [ternary], rather than base 10, expansions).

The big result you are trying to prove is a special case of one in fractal geometry.

to set this up, it is simple to see that $E$ is an *attractor* of the following contractions, $f_4, f_7: [0,1] \to [0,1],$

$$f_4(x) = \frac{x+4}{10},\qquad f_7(x) = \frac{x+7}{10}$$

(in digit form, these are: $f_i:0.d_1d_2d_3\ldots \; \mapsto 0.\,\underline{i}\,d_1d_2d_3),$

where *attractor* here means: $E$ is a compact subset of $[0,1]$ ($[0,1]$ being the domain) such that $E = f_4(E) \sqcup f_7(E)$.

From fractal geometry, it is known that attractors are 1) unique and 2) satisfy the following formula.

$$E = \bigcap_{n= 1}^\infty \;\;
\bigcup_{(i_1,\ldots,i_n)\in \{4,7\}^n}
\underbrace{f_{i_1}\circ f_{i_2}\circ f_{i_3}\circ \cdots \circ f_{i_n}[0,1]}_{\text{first $n$ digits are }i_1,\ i_2,\ldots i_n} $$

Furthermore,
$$ E_n = \bigcup_{(i_1,\ldots,i_n)\in \{4,7\}^n}
f_{i_1}\circ f_{i_2}\circ f_{i_3}\circ \cdots \circ f_{i_n}[0,1],$$

where this last equality follows by your definition of $E_n$ E.g.,

$$E_1 = f_4[0,1] \cup f_7[0,1]$$
$$E_2 = f_4\circ f_4[0,1] \cup f_4\circ f_7[0,1] \cup f_7\circ f_4[0,1] \cup f_7\circ f_7[0,1] $$

and so on.

In other words, this formula (or its proof) gives you another altenrative proof/viewpoint.

Other key words which apply: *iterated function system*, *self-similar sets*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The whole idea of my question was to show that $x \in \cap_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n \implies x \in E$. So, I assumed $x \in \cap_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n$, and then I attempted that the decimal expansion of $x$ is comprised exclusively of $4$ and $7$. I show that first digit of the expansion can only be $4$ or $7$, and I wanted to show that first digit of the expansion can only be $4$ or $7$ as well. Under the "regarding the second step of your induction," you show that $d_2 \notin \{4, 7\} \implies x \notin E$, and, sorry, but I am not sure how that answers that question at all.

Comment: Can you please explain what I'm missing? Also, I am not familiar with fractal geometry, so I cannot use that part of the answer.

Comment: Of course, let me clarify on the "second step": You've already shown $$x \in E \implies \text{first digit}(x) \in \{4,7\},$$ - this I'll refer to as your base case. 
What I'm saying is $$x \in E \implies f(x) \in E \stackrel{\text{base case}}\implies \text{first digit}\left(f(x)\right) \in \{4,7\} \iff \text{second digit}(x) \in \{4,7\},$$
since the first digit of $f(x)$ is, by construction, the second digit of $x$.

Comment: I.e. if $x$ is in $E$, the second digit is also in $\{4,7\}$ (as well as the first), i.e. $x \in E_2$. That proves $E \subset E_2.$

As for the fractal stuff, don't worry, I only put that in for "culture", and to give you a broader context for the question: E is a self-similar fractal, after all.

Comment: If $x$ is in $E$, then I don't need to show that each of the digits in its decimal expansion must be either $4$ or $7$-- this is true by the definition of $E$. I never assumed that $x \in E$--that is precisely what I am trying to show, assuming that $x \in \cap_{n = 1}^{\infty}E_n$. To be clear, I totally follow your argument in the case that $x$ is in $E$, but that's not what the question demands. Am I still missing something, or are there some typos somewhere, or is the issue bigger than that?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Let me edit that section now to give you the correct direction.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Under "a consequence of property 3," you claim that $\forall\,n\geq 2,\ f(x) \in f(E_n) = E_{n-1} \implies f(y) \in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty E_n.$ I think you meant to say that $\forall\,n\geq 2,\ f(y) \in f(E_n) = E_{n-1} \implies f(y) \in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty E_n.$, did you?

Comment: Yes, I did: corrected now!

Answer (score 0):

For each $n$, there exists an $a_n\in S_n$ such that $y\in \left[\frac{a_n}{10^n},\frac{a_n+1}{10^n}\right]$.

The last two digits of $a_{n+2}$ are either $44,47,74$ or $77$.

Without loss of generality assume that the last two digits of $a_{n+2}$ are $44$. We know that $10^{n+2}y\in [a_{n+2},a_{n+2}+1]$, so $10d_{n+1}+d_{n+2}$ is either $44$ or $45$. Therefore $d_{n+1}=4$.

Comment: How is it that $10^{n+2}y\in [a_{n+2},a_{n+2}+1] \implies 10d_{n+1}+d_{n+2}$ is either $44$ or $45$?

Comment: I think $10^{n+2}y = d_{1} d_{2} \dots d_{n+1}d_{n+2}. d_{n+3}d_{n+4}\dots$